# Comparing dates between mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a bug I guess, the database records the date format as YYYY-MM-DD, below is the table:-

[image: table]

The 1st table is the funds and the second is the fundshistory, as you can see LibraIncomeExtra Fund has the same date, but it still show stars.
Below is my coding:-

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM funds");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$getdate = date('y-m-j');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<center>";

if ($row['nav'] != $row['oldnav'])
{

if ($row['date_update'] != $getdate)
{
echo "" .$row['fundname']. "**";
$latestupdate = $row['date_update'];
}

}
else
{
    echo $row['fundname'];

}



echo "</center>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo"<center>";
echo $row['nav'];
echo "</center>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";


  }
?>
```

Anyone can explain this?
I know mysql extension is decprecated, but this coding was made long time ago, so I don't wish to redo to whole system by just changing mysqli extension.

Comment: Except I update it with same value of NAV then it the stars in missing else it won't.

Comment: What happens if you var_dump both of the fields right where you compare them.. I'm begging firestream is right below, needs a capital Y

Comment: `$getdate` is set to the current date of the server so `date_update` will only equal `$getdate` if the script is run when the server date equals `date_update`. What are you trying to accomplish with this script?

Comment: @Stephen WILL try it out later.

Comment: @JDavis Don't you get it? If the date last update on database and today's date is different then it will echo the fund name with # else just the fund name?

Comment: Well in that case – firestream's answer should suffice. (that is if you mean `**` by `#`)

Comment: I did try to change it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Well if you run the script now then todays date will not equal `date_update` in your example.

Comment: I'm sure you have other entries in the database, but with the information I'm given and other deductive reasoning – that is the best answer I have. ( and by some chance, might help )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself by using this coding:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM funds");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$getdate = date('Y-m-d');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<center>";

if ($row['date_update'] == $getdate)
{
    echo "" .$row['fundname']. "**";
    $latestupdate = $row['date_update'];
}

else
{
    echo $row['fundname'];
}


echo "</center>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo"<center>";
echo $row['nav'];
echo "</center>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";




 }
?>
```

The reason why it shows star is because using while for each line is being checked, as you refer the top previous coding I made, it is satisfy both statement, which require nav and old nav to be different which is true according to the table, next the date from database on table funds and current date on $getdate, which is both are also different that cause both statement to be true and execute the if statement coding. It is kinda stupid for me for not to see the mistake on the if condition. Thanks to firestream for giving that $getdate solution. AND I MADE A MISTAKE, the fundshistory table does not involved in this error.

THIS IS A TRICKY QUESTION :D 
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is how you declare $getdate

Try this instead:
    $getdate = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: Doesn't seems to work.  I try putting elseif statement if the date are the same, then echo without stars, still show stars.

Comment: @user1631889, i think **firestream**'s advise right. Check return value of php `data` function, print it out.